# Android Studio - Make simulator separate from studio itself

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

When I start my React Native project using command `npx react-native run-android`, I got
[a simulator window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo7wF.png).

However, when I hit the launch button in Android Studio, the simulator appears [in a small window inside Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdVtg.png).

Is there anyway to start the simulator like in the first picture manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the new Update the Emulator always starts inside AS but you can get the old look back by doing this:

1. Go to Preferences of Android Studio
2. Search for emulator, or navigate to tools -> Emulator
3. Uncheck the Launch in a tool window